# equivalent of size_t in F#

Tags: f#

I see that in F# the type of List.length is 'a list -> int

Is it safe to assume that int will always be big enough to contain the size of any list I might create, and is that because lists are limited to 4G items?

The book I am learning from (Expert F# 2.0) says that int and int32 are the same size, so I set off writing my first program with a typedef for size_t. That is a pain because it requires me to explicitly tell the compiler what type constants I mean (e.g. 7UL instead of just 7), although I expect that could be avoided by turning size_t into an object with an int constructor. I also expect that would cause a range of other problems :-(

So, what is the usual solution please? Do I just use ints everywhere and ignore the 4G barrier? Array indices are ints too, so it's not like I would be able to do much useful with my size_t type even if I should be able to implement it well enough to use.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The literal equivalent of `size_t` in F# is [`unativeint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353715.aspx), but you rarely use this type in practice except when doing P/Invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET, you can only allocate an array that has 2GB (even if you're using 64 bit version and have enough memory). If you actually wanted to store this ammount of data, then you'd probably want to use arrays, because F# lists have larger overhead.

For this reason, you probably don't need to worry about the length being limited to 32bit `int`. The only case where you would care is if you were writing data structure to workaround this 2GB limitation.

Comment: Many thanks. That's rather disappointing, and a wart on an otherwise excellent language. While I don't need data structures with >2G elements right now, I expect everyone will want them eventually, just like everyone eventually wanted more than 640k of RAM. It also means putting in an awful lot of explicit checks because ints wrap around silently. Still, thanks again.

Comment: @user982776: then you could probably find a better data structure. For instance in 3D rendering, you don't store a texture of say 16k*16k pixels in one big array but rather a vector of mipmaps, each mipmap being a vector of small cache friendly blocks that can be loaded on demand.

Comment: @user982776 Yes - it is a bit unfortunate thing about .NET. Early users of F# at Microsoft Research who did some machine learning on huge data sets hit this limitation - but then, you can find some hierarchical representation (array of arrays) which will work fine...

Answer (score 2):

An array of 4G ints, would require 16GB of RAM, and that's only for ints (and not anything more complex). Unless you have that much memory, there's no reason to care about that limit. If you do want to use that much memory, consider splitting you array into 2-3 arrays.

Comment: Also: if you do reach a point where you need 16GB of RAM, there's a good change you're just doing something wrong. That's a crazy amount of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, use "int" for collection sizes.  It is big enough for the 99.999% case, and it is best to have standard types across all APIs.